# Getting RAD builds and Jenkins builds to play nice

Tags: eclipse, svn, jenkins, build-process, rad

I have about 50 projects in version control for which I am standardizing the way that they are structured and built.

Each has a build.xml in its root folder. We also have a project in which there is a build file that gets imported by the other projects in order to do common tasks. This makes maintenance of these common tasks much easier.

SVN Repositories for each project adhere to svn standard root structure of trunk/tags/branches. Our workspaces are built in RAD by checking out from trunk. When rad then builds the project structure there is no actual trunk directory created on the filesystem. Projects simply begin in workspaceRoot/projectName, without the trunk. Although the infomation about where the project was checked out from is in brackets after the project name, so you know what branch of the repository you are working on.

We support both File->Export style war creation in RAD and explicit build.xml creation of the war file as well. All of this is working just peachy.

Now starting to get these projects building nightly in Jenkins and struggling with some of the file structure differences between the RAD environment and the Jenkins Environment.

For instance, if I have a specific project I am working on, say project1, the build.xml location in my workspace will be

```
workspaceRoot/project1/build.xml
```

The common build.xml file similarly will be at

```
workspaceRoot/commonProject/build.xml
```

So project1 will attempt to import that build file with

```
 <import file="${basedir}/../commonProject/build.xml"/>
```

In Jenkins however when I specify the repository location and it does its checkout it goes to

```
jenkinsRoot/workspace/jobName/project1/trunk/build.xml
```

and similarly the common project build.xml is at

```
jenkinsRoot/workspace/jobName/commonProject/trunk/build.xml
```

So the syntax in the project1 build file to import the common build file will not work.
I have other similar issues, all related to differences in file structure.

It seems this must be a fairly common issue, is there an "best practice" approach to addressing problems such as this. I have done a deal of searching around with no luck thus far.

Would be nice, for instance, if Jenkins could check out the trunk in the same way as RAD, but it does not seem that it can. This at least would allow me to use an ant "available" tag to look for the two possible trunk locations and use the correct one as appropriate. But one has a trunk and one does not. Jenkins includes the jobName in the workspace path, while obviously RAD has no such concept ... and so on. Would like a clean way of putting together a build process that works seamlessly whether launched from Rad or Jenkins.

-Jim

Comment: what is the svn URL that you use for checkout? Does it end with trunk?

Comment: In Jenkins it does not have the trunk ... If I provide trunk on the URL to Jenkins it complains that the given URL doesn't contain a repository ... Jenkins is insisting that only the path to the base of the repository be given. In RAD the repository is also mapped without the trunk, but you can specify the trunk when you do the checkout.

Comment: Something is wrong with your URL. I always supply trunk or branches/<branchname> or tags/<tagname>.

Comment: Jenkins insists on that location. I was able to get the checkout I wanted by not using the SCM portion of the job configuration and just doing a separate Jenkins shell command  where I was able to provide the desired URL

Comment: can you give us the configuration that you use? I *can* checkout only a single branch/tag or just trunk. There is a second field (*Local module directory (optional)*) under the URL as well, where I can tell it to put my checkout wherever I want it.